# SKlearn Minimum Covariance Determinant (MCD) Function yields different results if applied to whole data array vs looped

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science, covariance

I have a repeated experiment (n=K) which measures time series of equal length N, i.e. my data matrix has the shape NxK. I now want to compute a robust estimate of the covariance between the experiments for which I use the Minimum Covariance Determinent algorithm implemented in Sci Kit Learn. 
One way to apply the algorithm is to directly apply the function to the data array D, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.covariance import MinCovDet
N = 300 #number of rows
K = 40 #number of columns
D = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(N, K)) #create random Data

mcd = MinCovDet().fit(D) #yields a KxK matrix
cov_mat = mcd.covariance_ #covariances between the columns
```

another way is to loop over the experiments

```
cov_loop = np.zeros((K, K))

for i in range(0, K):
    for j in range(i, K):
        temp_arr = np.zeros((N, 2))
        temp_arr[:, 0] = D[:, i]
        temp_arr[:, 1] = D[:, j]

        mcd_temp = MinCovDet().fit(temp_arr)
        cov_temp = mcd_temp.covariance_ #yields 2x2 matrix, we are only interested in the [0,1] element

        cov_loop[i, j] = cov_temp[0, 1]
        cov_loop[j, i] = cov_loop[i, j]

print(cov_loop/cov_mat)
```

The results differ significantly, which is why I wanted to ask what went wrong here.

Comment: As far as I understand, the two shouldn't be equivalent. The different results would come from the `c_step` function which searches for the subset of observations "whose scatter matrix has the minimum determinant". That step will give you different results as you add additional features to consider. I.e. the pairwise calculation wouldn't be the same as the calculation over the whole dataset.